# How do I pull THIS off? With "this" listener

Tags: javascript, onclick, this

I've multiple elements that all have the same ID (player-left). Can I use JS "this" to only do something to whichever div is being clicked and not the others?

*This obviously doesn't work but just for questions sake...*

```
player_left.onclick = function() {
    this.player_left.classList.add("active");   
}
```

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID, as ID is the [attribute that is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

Comment: Aside from what Jay said, your code isn't working because `this` is the element that was clicked. Try `this.classList.add("active")`

Answer (score 0):

**Replace use of `id` attributes**

Using the same `id` attribute value on multiple elements is not valid.

Try looking into `element.querySelector` and or `element.querySelectorAll` methods to find elements matching a CSS selector string (See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for method details). Then change the `id` attribute of elements (**plural**) with the same id to use a unique class name  or data attribute to identify player elements.

**Event Delegation or multiple event handlers**

Where to add click handlers depends on whether you use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/5217142) or assign multiple click handlers to multiple elements. In general

- the `this` value inside a click handler (added to an element in JavaScript) is the element to which the handler was added. Handlers are passed an `Event` object (covered on MDN) as their first argument.
- The event object's `currentTarget` property is set to the element to which the event listener was added, and
- The `target` property of the event object is set to the element on which the click event was fired. If the player object has child elements, the `target` object may be a child element that was clicked.